# Nuxt access store (in Module mode) from JS file

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I have an AuthService that I use in a namespaced store in my Nuxt app. I need to commit mutations from AuthService to the namespaced store but I can't figure out how to import the store into my AuthService.

I've seen examples where the store is imported into the JS file, but the store is explicitly defined in the Vue app. Because I'm using Nuxt with the Module mode for my store, I'm not sure of the root path where I can import my store into the AuthService file. As I understand it, Nuxt handles creating the root store and all the namespaced store behind the scenes when use "Module mode"

My Nuxt `store` directory includes `index.js` (which is empty) and `auth.js` which has the mutations I want to call from AuthService.

**auth.js**

```
import AuthService from '../firebase/authService'

const authService = new AuthService()

export const state = () => ({
  user: null
})

export const mutations = {
  setUser (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async signUp ({ commit }, payload) {
    try {
      await authServices.createUser(payload)
      return Promise.resolve()
    } catch (err) {
      const notification = {
        duration: 5000,
        message: err.message,
        type: 'error'
      }
      commit('ui/activateNotification', notification, { root: true })
      return Promise.reject()
    }
  }
}
```

**authService.js**

```
import { fAuth, fDb } from './config'

// I think I need to import auth store here but I'm not sure how

export default class AuthClient {
  async createUser (payload) {
    try {
      const res = await fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      const { uid } = res.user
      const user = {
        ...payload,
        uid
      }
      await this._createUserDoc(user)
      this._initAuthListener()
      return Promise.resolve()
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    }
  }

  async _createUserDoc (user) {
    await fDb.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(user)
  }

  _initAuthListener () {
    fAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      try {
        if (user) {
          const userProfileRef = fDb.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
          const userProfileDoc = await userProfileRef.get()
          const { uid, userName } = userProfileDoc.data()

          // Here is where I want to call a mutation from the auth store

          this.store.commit('setUser', {
            uid,
            userName
          })
        } else {
          this.store.commit('setUser', null)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you finally find a solution  ?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to propose a solution using a plugin.

In the external module (`externalModule.js`) we define `store` variable and export an `init` function that receives `Nuxt context` as argument. The function assignes the `store` from `context` to the variable which can be now used in the module:

```
let store;
export function init (context) {
    store = context.store;
};
(...further business logic using store)
```

Then in the plugins folder we create a plugin file (let's call it `storeInit.js`). The file imports the `init` function from the external module and exports default plugin function required by Nuxt. The function receives `context` from Nuxt and we call the `init` function passing the `context` further:

```
import { init } from '[pathTo]/externalModule.js';
export default (context, inject) => {
    init(context);
};
```

Then we register the plugin in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/storeInit' }
    ],
    ...
}
```

This way when the app is built by Nuxt and plugins are registered, the `context` object is passed to the external module and we can use anything from it, among others the `store`.

Comment: really nice solution

Answer (score 2):

In `index.js` file which is in store folder you need to return store like this

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      counter: 0
    },
    mutations: {
      increment (state) {
        state.counter++
      }
    }
  })
}

export default createStore
```

and in your `authService.js` file you need to import store like this

```
import $store from '~/store'
```

by this you will be able to access your store

```
$store.commit('setUser', null)
```

I hope this works for you

Important Note: you don't need to install vuex because it is already shipped with nuxtjs

Comment: But will this not break Nuxt build process? Nuxt specifies how the store's `index.js` should look like and it expects it to export store's main properties (state, mutations, etc) from which it creates the store's instance. It does not expect an already created instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can access as window.$nuxt.$store

Note: My nuxt version is 2.14.11